# BCD to bargraph decoder vhdl design code

Tags: vhdl, hdl

The inputs represent a binary value between 0 and 9. There are nine outputs. Each output drives an LED. When an output is 0, its associated LED is ON. When it is 1, its associated LED is OFF. The LEDs are stacked in a vertical bar. The top LED is driven by bar_graph(8) and the bottom LED is driven by bar_graph(0).

I have pasted my code here and it has a few errors and i am not sure if this is the correct way.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

entity bcd_2_bar is 

port (bcd : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0); 

  bar_graph : out std_logic_vector (8 downto 0)); 

end bcd_2_bar; 

architecture test of bcd_2_bar is

begin

  bar_graph<="111111111" when "0000" else 

  bar_graph<="111111110" when "0001" else

  bar_graph<="111111100" when "0010" else

  bar_graph<="111111000" when "0011" else

  bar_graph<="111110000" when "0100" else 

  bar_graph<="111100000" when "0101" else

  bar_graph<="111000000" when "0110" else

  bar_graph<="110000000" when "0111" else

  bar_graph<="100000000" when "1000" else 

  --nothing is displayed when number greater than nine.

  bar_graph<="111111111" when others;

end test;
```

Comment: You need to check the correct syntax for "conditional assignment statements".

Answer (score 0):

You have not written a properly formatted statement. You could do one of the following:

```
bar_graph <= "111111111" when bcd = "0000" else
             "111111110" when bcd = "0001" else
             "111111100" when bcd = "0010" else
             "111111000" when bcd = "0011" else
             "111110000" when bcd = "0100" else
             "111111111";
```

or

```
with bcd select bar_graph <=
             "111111111" when "0000",
             "111111110" when "0001",
             "111111100" when "0010",
             "111111000" when "0011",
             "111110000" when "0100",
             "111111111" when others;
```

or

```
process(bcd)
begin
  case bcd is
    when "0000" => bar_graph <= "111111111";
    when "0001" => bar_graph <= "111111110";
    when "0010" => bar_graph <= "111111100";
    when "0011" => bar_graph <= "111111000";
    when "0100" => bar_graph <= "111110000";
    when others => bar_graph <= "111111111";
  end case;
end process;
```

I didn't include all your bcd values, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity bcd_2_bar is
  generic (
    led_on : std_logic := '0');
  port (
    bcd       : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    bar_graph : out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0));
end entity bcd_2_bar;

architecture rtl of bcd_2_bar is
begin
  led_driver: process (bcd) is
  begin
    for led in bar_graph'range loop
      bar_graph(led) <= not led_on when bcd > bar_graph'length else
                        led_on when led < bcd else
                        not led_on;
    end loop;
  end process led_driver;
end architecture rtl;
```